# USB speed improvements

Tags: usb

If my program is downloading data from a device through USB to a PC and the device has a USB 2.0 port to send data, would there be any advantage to plugging the other end to a USB 3.0 port on the PC? Or would I strictly be limited to usb 2.0 speeds. What else can I do to speed up USB transfer rates, if anything?

Answer (score 5):

The transfer speed is limited by the slower end of the connection. I don't believe there is anything you can do to help it further.